# New Customers after rows filtering

Tags: powerbi, dax

i have used the DAX code below in Power BI (DAX patterns 2015), which works fine to get NEW CUSTOMERS.
Customer is counted as NEW either if he uses Product_1 or Product_2.
Now I would like to create the same, but this time related to each product separately. So NEW CUSTOMER PRODUCT_1 measure would be if the client started to use Product_1 for the first time (without any regard to Product_2).
 In the data model FACT table I have Column with Product 1 and 2, if in one month was used only Product 2, then the Product 1 is blank in the same row and vice versa.
I tried to add 
    **Filter(MAIN;MAIN([Product_1]>0))**
but it gave me strange results. The new clients repeated whole year, instead of being counted only once.

```
Absolute_NEW_Customers(PRODUCT_1) = 
COUNTROWS ( 
         FILTER(
                ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES(MAIN[Customer No]);"PreviousSales";
                        CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(MAIN);FILTER(ALL('DateKey');DateKey[Date]<MIN('DateKey'[Date]))));
       [PreviousSales]=0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the function that helped. It was necessary to use the **"CALCULATETABLE"** function by which I filtered the whole table. Below is the final code:

```
Absolute_NEW_Customers(Product_1) = 
COUNTROWS ( 
FILTER(
       ADDCOLUMNS(
                 CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(MAIN[Customer No]);FILTER(MAIN;NOT ISBLANK(MAIN[Product_1])));"PreviousSales";
                        CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(CALCULATETABLE(MAIN;FILTER(MAIN;NOT ISBLANK(MAIN[Product_1]))));FILTER(ALL('DateKey');DateKey[Date]<MIN('DateKey'[Date]))));
       [PreviousSales]=0))
```